# Why can't I insert a Calendar or a date time picker in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to insert a Calendar in WPF application by inserting calendar tags but I'm getting this error?

**The type 'calendar' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built**
Here is the code :-

```
<Window x:Class="HomeExpenseCalculator.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Window1" Height="395.516" Width="445.511">
    <Grid>
        <Label Height="25" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88" FontSize="14" Margin="14,15,0,0" Background="White">Person</Label>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="159.984,15,95.546,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBoxItem>Pankaj</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Shad</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Kartik</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Abhinav</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Rahul</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Height="28" Margin="3,63.327,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="99" FontSize="12" Background="White">Stuff   Purchased</Label>
        <TextBox Height="63" Margin="111,48,38,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Calendar> </Calendar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Show us the code :) (have you tried Calendar with an upper case 'C' ?)

Comment: I've added the code above

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: it is version 3.5 (VS 2008)

Comment: So then you can't use Calendar and DatePicker - they were included in WPF in .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

I created a new window and added the calender control with no errors. Here is what the XAML looked like:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Calendar />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I've posted the code above. Please take a look. The Calendar tag is not working...

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and pasted it into a test project and had no issues at all.

Comment: Maybe try restarting Visual Studio.  Other that that I'm not sure what could be wrong, the code looks just fine.  Unless its like the others are saying and you are missing the assembly reference (which should be already included by default).

Comment: Mine gives two errors Error 1 The tag 'Calendar' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 16 Position 10 2 The type 'Calendar' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: Is this a WPF application? Or are you adding a WPF Window to a WinForms application?

Comment: Try creating a new window and just putting the calendar control in it.  If that doesn't work, try creating a new test project and placing the calender in the window for that project.  It should work in at least the latter instance and then compare with what you have.  If it still isn't working at all, then there must be a bigger problem that I won't be able to diagnose.

Comment: I created a new project. I'm still not able to insert calendar. Actually all the common controls in toolbox are coming as grey. I can't drag and drop any of them.

Comment: Try resetting your toolbox like indicated by this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871531/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-controls-disabled-or-inactive

Comment: No luck!. I think I'll have to reinstall the Visual Studio. There seems to be some serious problem.

Comment: Someone commented above. I think calendar and datepicker is not available in .net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Please be more detailed in your question.

This error means you don't have the correct assembly.

See: [WPF assembly reference missing - project still building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432624/wpf-assembly-reference-missing-project-still-building)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have a reference to the correct namespace in the XAML? (i.e. xmlns=...).

You need to reference the namespace that the calendar control is in for it to work...

Comment: what should I insert here ?
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Answer (score 0):

use `Calendar` instead of 'calendar'

Comment: Error 1 The tag 'Calendar' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 16 Position 10. C:\Documents and Settings\Shad\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HomeExpenseCalculator\HomeExpenseCalculator\Window1.xaml 16 10 HomeExpenseCalculator