# The name "ChartPlotter" does not exist in the namespace "http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

Hi I am using the Dynamic Data Display library that I got from codeplex.com/dynamicdatadisplay. I saved my copy in the root directory and added the reference to the DLL of the DynamicDataDisplay.dll file to my project. However the xaml does not recognize the ChartPlotter and is saying "The name "ChartPlotter" does not exist in the namespace "http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0". Does anyone know what's the problem?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Margin="10,10,20,10">
            <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
                <d3:HorizontalDateTimeAxis Name="dateAxis"/>
            </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
            <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
                <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis Name="countAxis"/>
            </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>

            <d3:Header FontFamily="Arial" Content="Bug Information"/>
            <d3:VerticalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="Count"/>
            <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="Date"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media; // Pen

using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay; // Core functionality
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.DataSources; // EnumerableDataSource
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.PointMarkers; // CirclePointMarker

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);
        }

        private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<BugInfo> bugInfoList = LoadBugInfo("..\\..\\BugInfo.txt");

            DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[bugInfoList.Count];
            int[] numberOpen = new int[bugInfoList.Count];
            int[] numberClosed = new int[bugInfoList.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < bugInfoList.Count; ++i)
            {
                dates[i] = bugInfoList[i].date;
                numberOpen[i] = bugInfoList[i].numberOpen;
                numberClosed[i] = bugInfoList[i].numberClosed;
            }

            var datesDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<DateTime>(dates);
            datesDataSource.SetXMapping(x => dateAxis.ConvertToDouble(x));

            var numberOpenDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<int>(numberOpen);
            numberOpenDataSource.SetYMapping(y => y);

            var numberClosedDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<int>(numberClosed);
            numberClosedDataSource.SetYMapping(y => y);

            CompositeDataSource compositeDataSource1 = new
              CompositeDataSource(datesDataSource, numberOpenDataSource);
            CompositeDataSource compositeDataSource2 = new
              CompositeDataSource(datesDataSource, numberClosedDataSource);

            plotter.AddLineGraph(compositeDataSource1,
              new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2),
              new CirclePointMarker { Size = 10.0, Fill = Brushes.Red },
              new PenDescription("Number bugs open"));

            plotter.AddLineGraph(compositeDataSource2,
              new Pen(Brushes.Green, 2),
              new TrianglePointMarker
              {
                  Size = 10.0,
                  Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2.0),
                  Fill = Brushes.GreenYellow
              },
              new PenDescription("Number bugs closed"));

            plotter.Viewport.FitToView();

        } // Window1_Loaded()

        private static List<BugInfo> LoadBugInfo(string fileName)
        {
            var result = new List<BugInfo>();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] pieces = line.Split(':');
                DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(pieces[0]);
                int numopen = int.Parse(pieces[1]);
                int numclosed = int.Parse(pieces[2]);
                BugInfo bi = new BugInfo(d, numopen, numclosed);
                result.Add(bi);
            }
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return result;
        }

    } // class Window1

    public class BugInfo
    {
        public DateTime date;
        public int numberOpen;
        public int numberClosed;

        public BugInfo(DateTime date, int numberOpen, int numberClosed)
        {
            this.date = date;
            this.numberOpen = numberOpen;
            this.numberClosed = numberClosed;
        }

    }
} // ns
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely to be the "locked" dll issue. DynamicDataDisplay.dll has to be unlocked (check its properties).
related topic : [WPF assembly reference missing - project still building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432624/wpf-assembly-reference-missing-project-still-building)